# How do I check if NestedScrollView is currently scrolling?

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

I have a NestedScrollView and I want to see weather it is scrolling at the moment.

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {}

    });
```

I've looked online and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: what you actually want to do. There are basically two methods to detect scrolling in nestedscrollview. You can use them as per your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you will have to write your custom view which extend a NestedScrollView and in that view override the onScrollChange() methods and add logs inside that method to get the value of the scroll, you are writing a custom view as you cant add logs to the systems widgets.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 (With ScrollChangeListener)**

One option may be to store and compare `scrollY` and `oldScrollY` values within your `scrollChangeListener`. Something as simple as this might work (though it has not been formally tested):

```
private boolean scrollHasBeenChecked = false;
    
    nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            
            
            if(!scrollHasBeenChecked) {

                scrollHasBeenChecked = true;
                int scrollDif = scrollY - oldScrollY;
                
                final Handler handler0 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler0.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(scrollDif == scrollY - oldScrollY) {
                            
                            //Proceed
                            
                        } else {

                            scrollHasBeenChecked = false;
                            
                        }

                    }
                    //Adjust accordingly
                }, 250);
                
            }
            
        }

    });
```

**Option 2 (Without ScrollChangeListener)**

Depending on the context of your situation, you may be able to cross-check `scrollY` values. In my code, I needed to make my `recyclerView` visible after a programmatic scroll to the last visible position in my adapter class without overwriting a `scrollChangeListener` in my main class. If my `nestedScrollView.getScrollY() == lastVisiblePosition` (check in a delay runnable loop), then it is no longer scrolling*. A general solution based on this concept might work like:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

           int y = nestedScrollView.getScrollY();
           
           checkIfStillScrolling(y);

        }
        //Pick an appropriate delay time or replace runnable with some equivalent checking mechanism
    }, 1000);


private void checkIfStillScrolling(final int y) {

    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(y = nestedScrollView.getScrollY()){

                //Next step goes here

            } else {

                checkIfStillScrolling(y);

            }

        }
        //Pick an appropriate loop delay time
    }, 100);

}
```

*more or less - have to account for lifecycle, but that isn't relevant to this specifically